# filtering table rows on search makes the onClick not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table

I am facing this weird issue in my reactjs application. I am having an HTML table and I have a search bar which searches for whatever is entered in the bar, filters all the rows which have that searched term and then highlight it in these filtered rows. There is onkeyUp event attached to search input field. I have an onClick attached to all the rows.

**Problem:** When I search and then click on rows, the onClick doesn't work. When I click before I search anything, the onClick works.

**Suspected Issue:** Every time I search anything, on every onkeyup event, the table gets deleted completely and rebuilds with only the rows which have searched team in it. This might be taking away onclick method away from the new table which is built.

Here is my HTML and search function

```
 searchFunction() {


        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
        input = document.getElementById("search-table");
        var value = input.value



        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("speech-table");
        table.innerHTML=bak;
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
            var a1= td.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    var trimIndex=a1.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter);
                    var endIndex=trimIndex + filter.length + 3;
                    var output = [a1.innerHTML.slice(0, trimIndex), '<b>', a1.innerHTML.slice(trimIndex)].join('');
                    output = [output.slice(0, endIndex), '</b>', output.slice(endIndex)].join('');
                    a1.innerHTML=output;
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

my search input and table html

```
input type="text" id="search-table" onChange={() => this.searchFunction()}
                               className="form-control search-sentances pull-right"
                               placeholder="Search"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="panel-body scrollable no-pad-top-pad-bot2 sentance-scrollable">
                        <div className="subtitle-scroll">
                            <div className="tab-content">
                                <div className="tab-pane slide-left active" id="tab2sentancetable">
                            <table className="table sentance-table" id="speech-table">
                                <tbody>
                                {this.state.sentances_array.map((item, i) => (
                                    <tr key={item.id} id={item.id} onClick={() => this.sentance_click(item.time)}>
                                        <td className="edit-timing-sub"><span className="bold fs-12 text-success">{item.time.toFixed(2)}</span><br/>
                                            <span className="bold fs-12 text-success">{item.stopTime.toFixed(2)}</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <EditableTextField name='username' value={item.words} onUpdate={this.handleRowUpdate} placeholder='Enter spoken words'/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="#" className="text-danger fs-16"><span
                                                className="fa fa-pencil m-l-10"></span></a>
                                            <a href="#" className="text-danger fs-16"><span
                                                className="fa fa-trash m-l-10" onClick={()=>this.deleteRow(item.id)}></span></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                ))}


                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

How can I make onClick work even after the search?

Comment: You should completely rewrite your code. Never manipulate with DOM directly in react app. It is useless and make react unneeded. Just filter your state whenever user typed something in search input. Just forget about `document.getElement...` when you are using react.

Comment: So rather than rebuilding the table content why not filter the content and change the `css` for elements that return false to the filter? This would save removing items to rebuild them if the client changes the search and it will keep the event listeners for those elements....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
searchFunction(event) {
    let filterText = event.target.value;
    let outputArray = this.state.sentances_array.filter(el => {
      return item.words.indexOf(el) != -1;
    })

    this.setState({sentances_array: outputArray});
}
```

This is how should look your search function. Basically your are filtering your array when user type something and react rerenders table each time `state` changes.

Comment: Thanks Taras. Actually the row has three columns. I have to search or filter from seccond column only. That's why I was using  td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];  How can I include it here. Also can your please include the complete logic in your code. That would be a big help. Thanks in advance

Comment: In this case `filterCase` is text typed by user in search input and `el` is each element in `this.state.sentance_array` array. This is probably complete code. At least it should work with this.

Comment: Also I am getting "cannot read property state of undefined" error

Comment: All you need to know is based on what property you want to filter your table. I assumed that it was `words` property.

Comment: Change your input to this `input type="text" id="search-table" onChange={this.searchFunction.bind(this)}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157981/discussion-between-apurvg-and-taras-danylyuk).